# Как сохранить значения spinner в базе данных

Tags: java, android, база-данных, android-spinner

Я уже создал базу данных, но я без понятия, как прикрутить данные из spinner к бд.

Comment: Сначала выясните как хотя бы что-то в БД положить. Потом - как выполнить к-л код в момент выбора эл-та спиннера. Потом первый кусок кода пихните во второй. Если вы не знаете как первый кусок кода написать - то причём тут спиннер? Если второй - то при чём тут БД? Делите задачу на мелкие, не связанные меж собой части.

Comment: Какой базой данных пользуетесь?

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы записи из бд были в спиннере?

Comment: Хочется чтобы данные спинора попадали в Textview  и они успешно сохраняли это).Вот исходники  https://yadi.sk/d/ljCaMMDR3JG699,  если получиться объяснить что не так такому дуболому как я ,то я буду искренне благодарен.